# How to fix «Python scripting is not supported in this copy of GDB»

Tags: python, configuration, gdb

The `configure` script was launched like

```
./configure --with-python=yes  --host=arm-linux-gnueabi
```

So, the python is enabled. Also in the [log of configure script](http://pastebin.com/JmiFARUe) I didn't found anything bad related to the python. But anyway, the compiled gdb keep saying

```
$ ./gdb -q
/home/constantine/.gdbinit:7: Error in sourced command file:
ind_string_in_backtrace (gdb.Function)::1: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined command: "class".  Try "help".
(gdb) py print("hello")
Python scripting is not supported in this copy of GDB.
```

The error you can see after I entered in gdb is also about Python *(the script that loaded on autostart)*. I did tried `make clean`, but it didn't helped. I hope someone knows the solution, I am really need a scripting, and hence the python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing python development libraries (python-dev package or variations on Ubuntu, python-devel on CentOS) on your build machine.

When configuring gdb there is no mention of python in top level config log of gdb.

Try building like this:

```
make 1> out.log 2> err.log
```

Then search for python in out.log. You should see something like this, to get working python scripting.

```
checking whether to use python... auto
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python2.7... yes
checking compiler flags for python code...  -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -fwrapv
checking whether python supports threads... yes
```

Comment: Didn't worked ☹ I am installed a python packages, and from what I see in the [output](http://pastebin.com/gSeSDAEX) it is actually compiled some files for a python support. But after I'm launch it, it is still keeps talking `Python scripting is not supported in this copy of GDB.`. In the err.log was just two lines «Creating observer.htmp
Creating observer.itmp» which, as it looks to me, appeared there just accidentally.

Comment: Can you post relevant lines from out.log?

Comment: I am leaved a link http://pastebin.com/gSeSDAEX in the above comment ☺ Anyway, I'm at the moment striving with the fact that gdb refused to compile at all after some recompiling and cleaning.

Comment: That is not complete rebuild. Try make distclean or just rm object directory (or start using separate build directory: ../gdb-source-dir/configure --prefix=/your/install/dir etc).

Comment: Finally I did it. With the help of IRC. Your answer also important as I hadn't python dev files. But I'll also sum up what was needed to do for someone else: at first I had a typo: in the options I should write «target» instead of «host». Also it is important to configure'n'build everything in the root directory of sources. I suppose an option make no a sense since you'd anyway set it in the *gdb/* subdirectory. And the last: for unknown reasons compiling may fail with missing the «version.c» file. You have to copy `gdb/version.c-tmp` to `gdb/version.c`. Feelling like a warrior from crusade.